# Smart Search exclude search articles by author name

Tags: joomla-3.6, smartsearch

I have Joomla version 3.6.5 and Content Smart search version 3.0.0.

When we write author name in search box it will display articles written by that author. I want to stop this search. e.g. article search by author name.

I have tried as given here:

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-how-to-configure-smart-search.html#gref

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/smart-search/

I have create search filter with de-selected authors list and I have module with smart search, at there, I have select in search filter created in Components -> Smart Saerch -> Search Filter.

[image]

[image]

And search field in menu, I have selected this module. from IceMegaMenu Module.

[image]

But this not stopped search articles by author name.

I have also tried removing authors from content maps, but this also couldn't help.

I have also review [this](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/7976). As given solution here, I have to change in code, Is it true?

Please suggest right solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to add to this discussion, these changes would best be done in clones of the affected plugins so that you don't lose your changes the next time the core plugins are updated.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem... the indexer was including Author names on the smart search indexed content.

The only way that I could overcome this, was changing the indexer code, and commenting the code block responsible for Author's data.

Base_path/Plugins/Finder

Take a look at categories/categories.php and content/content.php files.
They both have the index function.

I commented the following lines: (content.php)

```
// $item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'metaauthor');
// $item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'author');
// $item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'created_by_alias');      
// Add the author taxonomy data.
if (!empty($item->author) || !empty($item->created_by_alias)) {
//          $item->addTaxonomy('Author', !empty($item->created_by_alias) ? $item->created_by_alias : $item->author);
}
```

And on categories.php:

```
// Add the meta-author.
//  $item->metaauthor = $item->metadata->get('author');

// Handle the link to the meta-data.
$item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'link');
$item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'metakey');
$item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'metadesc');
// $item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'metaauthor');
// $item->addInstruction(FinderIndexer::META_CONTEXT, 'author');
```

After that, clean your index and start again.

The only problem that I found, but hadn't time enough to troubleshoot was that the indexed content stopped appearing on smart search admin > indexed content list.

But if you try searching on your frontend, everything will work and authors gonna be skipped from search.

When I find how to fix this problem, i'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I will try this solution and get back to you.

Comment: If you want to skip TAG authors as well, do the same changes in the tag/tag.php file.